# Deadlock on concurrent update, but I can see no concurrency

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, firebird2.1

What could trigger a deadlock-message on Firebird when there is only a single transaction writing to the DB?

I am building a webapp with a backend written in Delphi2010 on top of a Firebird 2.1 database. I am getting an concurrent-update error that I cannot make sense of. Maybe someone can help me debug the issue or explain scenarios that may lead to the message.

I am trying an UPDATE to a single field on a single record.

```
UPDATE USERS SET passwdhash=? WHERE (RECID=?)
```

The message I am seeing is the standard:

```
deadlock
update conflicts with concurrent update
concurrent transaction number is 659718
deadlock
Error Code: 16
```

I understand what it tells me but I do not understand why I am seeing it here as there are no concurrent updates I know of.

Here is what I did to investigate.

I started my appplication server and checked the result of this query:

```
SELECT
   A.MON$ATTACHMENT_ID,
   A.MON$USER,
   A.MON$REMOTE_ADDRESS,
   A.MON$REMOTE_PROCESS,
   T.MON$STATE,
   T.MON$TIMESTAMP,
   T.MON$TOP_TRANSACTION,
   T.MON$OLDEST_TRANSACTION,
   T.MON$OLDEST_ACTIVE,
   T.MON$ISOLATION_MODE
FROM MON$ATTACHMENTS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN MON$TRANSACTIONS T
    ON (T.MON$ATTACHMENT_ID = A.MON$ATTACHMENT_ID)
```

The result indicates a number of connections but only one of them has non-NULLs in the MON$TRANSACTION fields. This connection is the one I am using from IBExperts to query the monitor-tables.

Am I right to think that connection with no active transaction can be disregarded as not contributing to a deadlock-situation?

Next I put a breakpoint on the line submitting the UPDATE-Statement in my application server and executed the request that triggers it. When the breakpoint stopped the application I then reran the Monitor-query above.

This time I could see another transaction active just as I would expect:

[image: screenshot of two active transactions]

Then I let my appserver execute the UPDATE and reap the error-message as shown above.

What can trigger the deadlock-message when there is only one writing transaction? Or are there more and I am misinterpreting the output? Any other suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: You might want to check `MON$TRANSACTIONS` on its own without joining to `MON$ATTACHMENTS`, and use gfix to check if there are [transactions in limbo](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gfix-transactions.html). BTW: deadlock is a bit of a misnomer, it is not a deadlock in the general sense of the word: here it means that there is a newer record version that is not visible to your current transaction.

Comment: To clarify: you can also get this error (depending on the transaction isolation, eg with consistency or concurrency) if another transaction modified the same record and that transaction was committed **after** your transaction started.

Comment: I can manually edit the field in IBExpert just before I trigger the Webrequest that later leads to the failure. So it propably is not something stuck for a long time, but confined to the request-lifecycle itself.

There is indeed another update to the record in the same request. For a different field, though.

I should know this, but don't: Is this concurrency-checking done on a per-record basis? If so I have a good lead...

Comment: Every update creates a new version of the record, so if in the same request you changed the same record in a different transaction (even if it was a different field), then that might be the problem if your current transaction started before the other transaction was committed. Looking at the screenshot you are using _concurrency_ (=1) as your transaction isolation in which case that would trigger this exception (using _read committed record version_ would - in most cases - not exhibit this error, but it relaxes some of the constraints which might not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Firebird uses MVCC ([Multiversion Concurrency Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)) for its transaction model. One of the features is that - depending on the transaction isolation - you will only see the last version committed when your transaction started (*consistency* and *concurrency* isolation levels), or that were committed when your statement started (*read committed*). A change to a record will create a new version of the record, which will only become visible to other active transactions when it has been committed (and then only for read committed transactions).

As a basic rule there can only be one uncommitted version of a record. So attempts by two transactions to update the same record will fail for one of those transaction. For historical reasons these type of errors are grouped under the *deadlock* error family, even though it is not actually a deadlock in the normal concurrency vernacular.

This rule is actually a bit more restrictive depending on your transaction isolation: for consistency and concurrency level there can also be no newer committed versions of a record that is not visible to your transaction.

My guess is that for you something like this happened:

1. Transaction 1 started
2. Transaction 2 started with *concurrency* or *consistency* isolation
3. Transaction 1 modifies record (new version created)
4. Transaction 1 commits
5. Transaction 2 attempts to modify same record

(Note, step 1+3 and 2 could be in a different order (eg 1,3,2, or 2,1,3))

Step 5 fails, because the new version created in step 3 is not visible to transaction 2. If instead *read committed* had been used then step 5 would succeed as the new version would be visible to the transaction at that point.